# objectdisposedexception c#

Tags: c#, winforms, objectdisposedexception, windows-mobile-6.1

Hello fellow programmers!

I`m developing a Windows Forms .NET Compact Framework 2.0 for a Windows Mobile 6.1 device that has a barcodereader hardware.

I can use the barcodereader to read barcodes, and I can activate and deactivate it as well. 
Except that when I try to read something and go to the next form I get a objectdisposedexception. That happens (I guess) because I have to dispose the instance of the barcode reader and then create a new one in the next form.

The problem is: when I use a button to go to the next form, using the same code to dispose the barcodereader I don`t have the objectdisposedexception. When I simply put the form load on the textchanged event the error rises, but is not caught by any try/catch statements, making the application crash.

I can`t debug it either, because the VS emulator to windows mobile does not work with the device barcodereader DLL.

Can someone help me?

Here`s the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//DLL that controls the barcodereader
using Intermec.DataCollection;

namespace WOPT_Coletor.view.ConsultarPosicao
{
    public partial class frmConsultarPosicao_2 : Form
    {

        public BarcodeReader leitor;

        public frmConsultarPosicao_2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowHide.ShowTopStatusbar(false);

            //code to work with the barcode reader
            model.LeitorCodigoDeBarras classeLeitor = new model.LeitorCodigoDeBarras();
            leitor = classeLeitor.LerCodigoDeBarras();
            leitor.BarcodeRead += new BarcodeReadEventHandler(this.eventoLeitorCodigoDeBarrasArmazenagem1);
        }    

        //Event to receive the barcode reading information
        void eventoLeitorCodigoDeBarrasArmazenagem1(object sender, BarcodeReadEventArgs e)
        {
            tbCodMaterial.Text = e.strDataBuffer.Trim();
        }

        private void tbCodMaterial_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tbCodMaterial.Text.Length == 23)
                {                        
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                    Cursor.Show();

                    //disposal of the barcodereader instance
                    leitor.ScannerOn = false;
                    leitor.ScannerEnable = false;
                    leitor.Dispose();
                    leitor = ((BarcodeReader)null);

                    //processing of the information read.
                    char[] auxcodMaterial = new char[9];

                    using (StringReader str = new StringReader(tbCodMaterial.Text))
                    {
                        str.Read(auxcodMaterial, 0, 8);
                    }    
                    string codMaterial = new string(auxcodMaterial);

                    //loads next form
                    Form destino = new frmConsultarPosicao_3(codMaterial);
                    destino.Show();

                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    Cursor.Show();

                    //closes and dispose of the current form
                    this.Close();
                    this.Dispose(true);
                }    
            }

            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for calling both Close and Dispose?  The Close method already invokes Dispose.

Comment: Is this Intermec software?  Review the top google hits for "BarcodeReadEventHandler", plenty of people had your problem.  And of course contact the vendor for help first, they'll know about this issue.

Comment: Mike, actually I don`t have a reason. Just put it to test (despair? LoL)

Comment: Yes, it is the Intermec Software. I`ve read all posts I`ve found over the internet without succees! But tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your barcode reader's API and behavior, I'd guess it's that you have a race condition where your BarCodeRead event could fire while you're inside tbCodMaterial_TextChanged. I would suggest placing a synchronization block around the code that disables the scanner, and inside the block only perform the shutdown if the scanner is non-null:

```
private readonly Object mySynchronizationObject = new Object;
...
lock (mySynchronizationObject)
{
    if (leitor != null)
    {
         //disposal of the barcodereader instance
         ...
    }
}
```

It also wouldn't hurt to disconnect from the event prior to shutdown (inside the above lock):

```
leitor.BarcodeRead -= new BarcodeReadEventHandler(this.eventoLeitorCodigoDeBarrasArmazenagem1);
```

Comment: Tks for your reply, but it still didin`t work... Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm. OK, time for some diagnostics. When you *do* see an exception, what are the first few frames of the stack? Does it appear to originate in tbCodMaterial_TextChanged, or elsewhere?

Comment: the first to frames point to the text box, so, yes, it appear to originate in tbCodMaterial_TextChanged